# Symfony 5 Delete methods, Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, twig, sql-delete

I wanted to put in my controller a second delete button to delete comments but I got lots of error messages like the one from ParamConverter because it did not recognize the class.

So in my controller I have a ParamConverter like this:

```php
/**
     * @Route("/delete/{comment_id}", name="comment_delete", methods={"DELETE"})
     * @ParamConverter("comment", class="App:Comment", options={"id": "id"})
     */
    public function deleteComment(Request $request, BlogPost $blogPost, Comment $comment, $comment_id): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete' . $comment->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->remove($comment);
            $entityManager->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('/');
        }


        return $this->render('comments/_delete_form.html.twig', [
            'comment' => $comment
        ]);
    }
```

In my twig, I added this:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('comment_delete', {'comment_id': comment.id}) }}" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token('delete' ~ comment.id) }}">
    <button class="btn delete">Delete</button>
</form>
```

But it creates an error message:

> "Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter" comment ".

Comment: I think you have something really odd in your logic because you made this out of another action. Hard to tell what exactly, without your entities, but I guess you don't need most of your function arguments, as I guess you can get the `BlogPost` out of something like `$comment->getPost()`, and your `comment_id` out of `$comment->getId()`. From there on, you don't need any complexity anymore and you can go: `* @Route("/delete/{id}", name="comment_delete", methods={"DELETE"})` and let the magic `ParamConvert` act on the signature of the function `public function deleteComment(Comment $comment) {`

Comment: Thanks to you ! My ParamConverter errors mostly came from my redirectToRoute.

Comment: Why do you call that parameter `comment_id` in the route definition and `id` in the annotation for your ParamConverter? Also, please don't use unrelated tags - to me, there is no relation to [tag:sql-delete] or [tag:twig]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, Symfony will try to convert the route parameters to entities [automatically](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#fetch-automatically) if you typehint them in the function signature. For example, since you don't use the `BlogPost` entity, you could just write:

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/{id}", name="comment_delete", methods={"DELETE"})
 */
public function deleteComment(Comment $comment): Response
```

You should change the parameter name in your twig function too, of course.

If you want to be more explicit and keep the parameter name as is, for clarity, you can write:

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/{comment_id}", name="comment_delete", methods={"DELETE"})
 * @ParamConverter("comment", options={"id" = "comment_id"})
 */
```

In order to map the route argument to the column name.

The error you are receiving is because you wrote `options={"id": "id"}` telling the converter to look up the entity by using the `id` parameter in the url, and of course there's no `id` parameter.

Comment: Thank you β.εηοιτ.βε and msg